# how to compare the List elements?

Tags: case

My scenario is to compare two list elements. If the condition gets satisfied, it will have to print 'Success' else 'Failure'.

I have a set of retrieved values in one list(named as AList) and a set of retrieved values in another list(named as BList).

Thanks in advance !!!!!!

Comment: can you share your current code, then we can suggest what to add / change to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check if values exists in lists then you can use this code.

```
Set<Obj__c> set1 = new Set<Obj__c>(list1);
Set<Obj__c> set2 = new Set<Obj__c>(list2);

for(Obj__c o : set1){
     if(!set2.contains(o) ){
          //your logic
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer Lsize;
List<String> PrintVar;

if(Alist.size() > Blist.size() )
  {
 Lsize = Alist.size();
   }
else
    {
 Lsize = Blist.size();
    }

for(integer i = 0; i< Lsize; i++)
   {
 if(Alist[i] == Blist[i])
    {
PrintVar.add(Alist[i]);
     }
  }
```

You can try this code if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming you’d like to check if a value in list A is contained in list B.  If this is the case, you can use maps. In theory you could use lists; however, it is not a best practice as you would approach governor limits with nested loops.

```
String val = null;
list<account> AList= new list<account>();
AList = [Select ID, AValue__c From account];

list<account> BList = new list<account>();
BList = [Select ID, BValue__c From Account];

map<string, account> BMap = new map<string, account>();
for (account b : BList){
   BMap.put(b.BValue__c, b);
}

for (account a: Alist){
  if (BMap.containsKey(a.AValue__c){
    val = ‘Success’;
  }
  Else {  val = ‘Failure’;  }
}
```